# Interpretation of Virial theorem in the case n=-2

Tags: virial-theorem

For potentials $V$ that fulfil $V(\lambda \vec{r}_1, \lambda \vec{r}_2, \ldots, \lambda \vec{r}_N) = \lambda^n V(\vec{r}_1,\vec{r}_2,\ldots, \vec{r}_N)$ one can rewrite the virial theorem as $$2\langle T \rangle = n \langle V \rangle.$$ 
In the case $n=-2$ it then follows that $\langle E \rangle= \langle T \rangle+\langle V \rangle = 0$. What is the meaning of this? Why is the average energy zero? One example for such a potential would be $V_{ij} = \alpha |\vec{r}_i-\vec{r}_j|^{-2}$.

Is this really a special case or am I attaching to much importance to the zero?

Comment: @lemon quite the opposite. The $n=-2$ Is a very special case known as the scale invariant potential. Already in QM it can give rise to fixed points and RG flow depending on the specific value of the coupling constant. For example, one can see that $n=-2$ is special by the fact that scaling solutions of the Schroedinger equation may exist in this case. I will post an answer if I find the time.